# Regular expression for search name of methods in java files

Tags: regex, ant

I´m want to get the name String `calculator();` in java files and replace with the String `//calculator`. How can I do that ? So, how can I write a  regular expression to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Ant, have you looked at the <[replaceregexp](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html)> task ?

Comment: Yes, I didn´t  find the regular expression because my regular expression is wrong, but the solution calculator\(\); solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're looking for, exactly, but the regular expression that would capture `calculator();` would be `calculator\(\);`